# How to get the number of letters of a word in python?

Tags: python

> This is what have tried but it's not working

```
lens("Father")
```

Answer (score 1):

it's `len('Father')` not `lens('Father')`

Answer (score 0):

`len(Father)`

Your mistake is the 's' at the end of len's'